# Git: merge two folders and get rid of one from the history

Tags: git, git-merge

Imagine that I have all my software in a 4GB folder named `A1`. Imagine that I am tracking `A1` together with another folder `Foo` that contains some documents.

My daily work consists in developing my software in `A1`, changing some files in `Foo` and perform some commit.

However, during my development I only change some files contained in `A1`. Other developers can change all the files in `A1`, but they are using another version control system. Every once in a while, they release an update version of `A1` and they ask me to integrate my code in the new release and continue my development from there. Let's call the folder released by the other developers `A2`.

The problem now is that I have the folder `A1` with my contribution that I am tracking through git, but now there is a new updated folder folder `A2` in some shared area that I shall use.

A simple solution from to this problem would be the following

```
git mv A1 A2
git commit
git checkout -b update_A1_A2
cp -rf MyCollegauesSharedSpace/A2 .
git add A2
git commit
git checkout master
git merge update_A1_A2
```

but in this case, I am afraid that my repo will grow very fast, since now in the history are present both `A1` and `A2`, and each one is of 4GB.

However, given that from now on I am only interested in developing on `A2`, it would be enough to cancel from the history all the previous commits that contains `A1`.

However, if on one hand I would get rid of all the `A1` (saving then 4 GB), on the other hand I would also get rid of the folder `Foo` that I want to keep. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using two directories A1 and A2? Aren't you jut mimicking what git will do for you anyway?

Also, it would be good to know what your artifact is? A patch for them? A finished compiled product? Are your contributions supposed to flow back into their version control system, and if so, how?

If i was in your shoes, i would create a branch 'pristine' for their developments, and only commit their changes to this branch, every time they do a new release. From that i'd create a branch with my contributions, and work only there. Every time they release a new version, i'd commit that to the pristine branch and tag it. Then i'd merge these changes to my development branch. This lets git take care of tracking file changes, and keeps the size manageable.